# Why aren't the $.mobile object properties registering when I test my app in firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-mobile, aptana

I'm trying to make an app using aptana studio and whenever I try to test it some of the code doesn't seem to register. Specifically, icons that I'm calling and the $.mobile object properties I wrote.

I get these error messages in the console:

> [GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs
> 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0 [GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0 [GPU 6432] WARNING: pipe
> error: 109: file
> c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc,
> line 346 [GPU 6432] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file
> c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc,
> line 346 [Child 8380] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file
> c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc,
> line 346
>
> #### !!! [Child][MessageChannel::SendAndWait] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv

I'm drafting the code based on a similar app I created that worked on an old computer so I'm pretty sure at the stage I'm at now (very beginning) there shouldn't be any problems with my code. I'm wondering if there's something wrong with firefox (the browser aptana seems to prefer I use to preview my app). Does anyone know why these elements are not appearing when I test my app?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
        Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

        <title>WVC</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="Cara">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyles.css"/>
    
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
             $(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
              $.mobile.page.prototype.options.defaultPageTransition="none";
              $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.theme="a";
              $.mobile.toolbar.prototype.options.theme="a";
              $.mobile.toolbar.prototype.options.addBacBtn="true;"
    
             })     
        
         </script>
     
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    
 
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Home Page Begins-->
        <div id="homeView" data-role="page" data-title="Wildlife Vehicle Collisions" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" id="header1">
              <h1>WVC</h1>
            </div>
        
            <div data-role="content">
                <img src="images/wildlife-3.jpg" alt="WVC Management"/>
                <div data-role="controlgroup">
                    <a href="#findView" class="ui-btn ui-icon-search ui-icon-left">Find Nearby</a>
                    <a href="#report" class="ui-btn ui-icon-eye ui-icon-left">Report Collisions</a>
                    <a href="#videos" class="ui-btn ui-icon-video ui-icon-left">Videos</a>
                    <a href="#photos" class="ui-btn ui-icon-grid ui-icon-left">Photos</a>
                </div> <!-- links -->
            </div> <!-- content --> 
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; Copyright  by me</p>
            </footer>    
        </div> <!-- page -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!